# Youtube videos showing error on Wordpress template

Tags: wordpress, youtube

Reference:
http://youngs.activationdevelopment.com/meet-malcolm/

I am trying to play the videos in place but am receiving the error "An error has occurred, please try again later."

I have tried several different ways to embed the videos, but am currently using the embed code straight from youtube:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Md0M5AuJmKU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have tried deactivating all of my plugins, accept for Advanced Custom Fields Pro which, when deactivated, breaks the page as it is used heavily.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: `This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1.[Learn More] hvonm7xQuYAHD=1;rel=0;showinfo=0`

`Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead.`

I get this in console i guess it might be host related. Very weird never happened to me :/

Comment: the error is a bit more specific on Chrome. Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://youngs.activationdevelopment.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, this is happening locally as well...and the videos start working if I cause a javascript error. I have gone through and removed each javascript plugin one at a time with no success. Completely stumped.